# Syntax for UNIANOVA in R

Tags: r, syntax, spss, lm, anova

I am trying to replicate the following SPSS Syntax for type I unianova in R

```
UNIANOVA FinH BY Site Provenance Block Genotype WITH SoilNkh dDDSP dDDSP2
/RANDOM=Block Genotype
/METHOD=SSTYPE(1)
/INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
/POSTHOC=Site (SNK) 
/SAVE=PRED RESID
/CRITERIA=ALPHA(0.05)
/DESIGN=SoilNkh Site dDDSP dDDSP2 Provenance Provenance*Site Genotype(Provenance)
Block(Site).
```

Where Site and Provenance are fixed, Genotype nested in Provenance and Block nested in Site are random and dDDSP, dDDSP2 and SoilNkh. It should be type I ANOVA.

The best I can come up with as far as R-syntax goes is

```
m11 <- lme(FinH ~ 1 + SoilNkh + Site + dDDSP + dDDSP2 + Provenance + Site:Provenance, 
    random = (1|Provenance/Genotype) + (1|Site/Block), data=spss)
Anova(m11,type="I")
```

and quite a few varieties (which shouldn't be possible :) ), but to no avail. I also got lost in everything Google has got to offer on the subject, frankly.

I'd greatly appreciate any help on translating the syntax.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

This seems to get me close:

```
FinH <- lmer(FinH~SoilN + Site + dDDSP + dDDSP2 + Provenance +
                  Site:Provenance +(1|Provenance/Genotype) + (1|Site/Block),
              REML = FALSE,
              data=subset(spss,Year=="2011"))
```

But as you can see not exactly identical. Also I haven't succeeded in calculating statistics for random effects. I'll keep working of course, to replicate the analysis, but further tips (and tricks) are always welcome.

[image: R vs SPSS]